# SOCIALENGINE4: set or update gender field of the users

Tags: php, sql, socialengine

How can I ADD male gender to all users using sql query? here is my code and i want to include Male Gender field.

```
    $table = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('users', 'user');

    $db = $table->getAdapter();
    $db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $user = $table->createRow();
        $user->displayname = $displayname;
        $user->save();

        $id = $user->getIdentity();

        $user->email = $firstName . $id . '@mail.com';
        $user->username = $firstName . $id;
        $user->enabled = 1;
        $user->approved = 1;
        $user->verified = 1;
        $user->save();

        $user->setPhoto($imagePath);

        $userItem = $usersTable->createRow();
        $userItem->item_id = $id;
        $userItem->save();

        $this->_activateSubscription($user);

        $db->commit();

    }
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a row in **engine4_user_fields_values** with user ID, field meta ID and field option ID. Here are the IDs we need :

```
Gender [field_id  : 5] in engine4_user_fields_meta

Male   [option_id : 2] in engine4_user_fields_options

Female [option_id : 3] in engine4_user_fields_options
```

I wrote both female and male options in the following code. Use one as needed and remove the other.

```
$fieldsValuesTable = Engine_Api::_()->fields()->getTable('user', 'values');

$row = $fieldsValuesTable->createRow();
$row->item_id = $user->getIdentity();
$row->field_id = 5; //Gender
$row->value = 2; //Male
$row->value = 3; //Female
$row->save();
```

Comment: thank you very much, 
have another question if not mind. 
what about Country.

Comment: You can look at the engine4_user_fields_meta table to find the ID for country. If the answer was helpful please mark it as the correct answer.